# Java is using 100% of cpu on linux

Tags: java, linux, cpu-usage

On my linux server, any java program (even the "Hello world") uses 100% of cpu and is very very slow. Id does not depend on the java version, I have tried different versions of openjdk and sun jdk, both behave the same. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution in this article http://blog.wpkg.org/2012/07/01/java-leap-second-bug-30-june-1-july-2012-fix/

There is a great chance, this is caused by the "leap second kernel bug". Firstly, check for the following in the `dmesg`

```
[10703552.860274] Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC
```

To fix it, firstly stop the ntp client. On debian-like systems

```
/etc/init.d/ntp stop
```

Store the current time

```
date -s now
```

And test the java. If everything is working correctly, try to restart ntp service

```
/etc/init.d/ntp start
```

And test it again.

Comment: Got excited when I saw this... Didn't work for me unfortunately.